# Structure of unit group of algebraic integers $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Dirichlet's unit theorem tells us that for any number field $K$, it is well known that the unit group $\mathcal{O}_{K}^{\times}$ of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ of $K$ is isomorphic to $\mu(K)\times \mathbb{Z}^{r+s-1}$, where $\mu(K)$ is a (finite) group of root of unities and free part corresponds to fundamental units.

My question is: is there any generalization of the theorem for infinite algebraic extensions? For example, let $\overline{\mathbb{Z}} = \mathcal{O}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ be a ring of algebraic integers. Can we describe $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}^{\times}$? I think it should be $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\oplus\left(\bigoplus \mathbb{Q}\right)$, where the direct sum has countably many copies of $\mathbb{Q}$, because it may be a direct limit of $\mathcal{O}_{K}^{\times}$. Is this true? If it is true, can we write element of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}^{\times}$ that corresponds to each $\mathbb{Q}$-summands? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The structure sounds right to me, $\overline{\mathbf Z}^\times$ should be a divisible group with torsion part the set of all roots of unity, so the structure follows from this also.
The second part of your question seems far harder to do in a natural way, if we write down such an isomorphism with $\bigoplus \mathbf Q$ we probably had to make a lot of choices along the way, in the order we considered the individual number fields at least.

Comment: @AlexJBest Thanks. I also think that it is impossible to find canonical elements correspond to each $\mathbb{Q}$. By the way, is it possible to find $N$ elements in $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}^{\times}$ such that they are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent (with respect to multiplication) for any $N$? For example, I strongly believe that $1+\sqrt{2}$ and $2+\sqrt{3}$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent, i.e. $(1+\sqrt{2})^{a}(2+\sqrt{3})^{b}\neq 1$ for any $(0, 0)\neq (a, b)\in \mathbb{Q}^{2}$.

Comment: @reuns Do you have any suggestions for that unit group? I also thought about that too.

Comment: There is probably more to say about $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_\infty)}^\times$ (the $\log$ of the [Minkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space_(number_field)) embedding of $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ is some lattice in some real subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ and we can try understanding how those vary with field extensions)